# Appointment scheduling nomenclature

Tags: terminology

My question is quite broad, thus I wasn't able to close it under a single title, so forgive me.

**Background:**

I can work between 9 a.m. and 5 p.m. on Mondays and Wednesdays, between 10 a.m. and 6 p.m. on on Tuesdays and Thursdays and between 8 a.m. to 1 p.m. and 3 p.m. to 7 p.m. on Fridays.

During that time I can have many appointments.

**Questions:**

1. How do you call an individual time period during which I work?
2. How do you call a group of all of those periods?
3. How do you call a time at which a single appointment starts?
4. How do you call the whole thing that would describe the time I usually work at and my appointments?

**My suggestions are:**

1. Working hours
2. Availability (but if I choose this word, how would I call my true availability, so working hours minus appointments?)
3. In polish we have a word for it, but it seems that in english you use `appointment` to describe both the date as well as the whole thing.
4. Schedule

Comment: We normally discourage multiple-facet questions, but I reckon your question just squeaks under the "too broad" line.

Comment: I don’t understand your having appointments during hours you claim to be available to work.

Answer (score 2):

The "individual time period during which I work" has a specific name in English: ***shift.*** [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shift) mentions it as describing the time worked:

> a group of workers who do a job for a period of time during the day or night, or the period of time itself
>
> > *I worked the last hour of my shift on autopilot.
> >
> > His shift starts at seven o'clock.
> >
> > She's just finished a 13-hour shift at the hospital.
> >
> > Studies revealed that doctors were routinely working 15-hours shifts.
> >
> > As her shift finishes, mine begins.*

The resourcing software I used to work on called the recurring group of shifts over a week the [***shift pattern***](https://workingtime-solutions.com/insight-and-events/blogs-latest-news/2017/01/examples-of-shift-patterns-and-examining-the-traditional-approaches-to-shift-working). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_plan) calls it a *shift plan, rota* or *roster,* although Google finds [images for *shift pattern*](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&tbm=isch&q=shift+pattern&chips=q:shift+pattern,g_1:work:92j5IauI0J0%3D). Different members of staff can work different shift patterns; and your shift pattern might change from week to week. It's simply the pattern of shifts that you work. This means that [***availability***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/availability) is fine for the time during which you are actually available.

The time at which a single appointment starts doesn't have a word in English. The appointment is the meeting which takes place, "I have an appointment at 10:15". So we would say "The appointment starts at 10:15." If you wanted to call it something, *appointment time* or *appointment start time* would be entirely understood.

The word *schedule* for the whole thing is a good word, although my subjective impression is that it's only recently come into widespread use (perhaps with computer diary/calendar software). "Let me see if I can fit your appointment into my schedule".

Comment: 'Shift' virtually demands an externally imposed (by the company etc) timeframe; I'm not sure whether OP means rather 'when I am available to work'.

Comment: The question wasn't exactly clear on that point, but I took it to mean that (that is "I can work" didn't mean "I can choose to work whatever period I want between these hours"). However, I don't believe there's another single word for a single work period, you'd need to say "I'm at work between 11 and 12" -- saying "My shift is 11 till 12" would be equally well understood.